# How to define a macro with parameters inside a beamer frame

Tags: macros, beamer

To ease the typesetting of nontrivial beamer frames I often employ local helper macros. This is not too easy in beamer, as defining a macro with parameters (e.g., `\def\myfmt#1{\emph{#1}}`) between `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` fails with:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \beamer@doifinframe.
<to be read again> 
               1
l.11 \end{frame}
```

The commonly mentioned workaround for this is to define the macro outside of the frame together with the latter inside a group:

```
\bgroup
\def\myfmt#1{\emph{#1}}
\begin{frame}[label=problem]{A frame that uses a ,,local'' macro}
  \myfmt{Slide content}
\end{frame}
\egroup
```

This, however, does not work if one wants to use the frame with `\againframe` later (complete MWE):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\bgroup
\def\myfmt#1{\emph{#1}}
\begin{frame}[label=problem]{A frame that uses a ,,local'' macro}
  \myfmt{Slide content}
\end{frame}
\egroup

\bgroup
\def\myfmt#1{\color{red} #1}
\begin{frame}{Another frame that uses a ,,local'' macro}
  \myfmt{Slide content}
\end{frame}
\egroup

% fails with "Undefined control sequence \myfmt"
\againframe{problem}

\end{document}
```

Apparently, `\againframe` does insert only the content that was defined between `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` - which makes sense, of course.

So how can I define "frame-local" helper macros that work with `\againframe`?

Comment: Use the `fragile` option or try to double the `#`: `\begin{frame}[label=problem]{A frame that uses a ,,local'' macro}
  \def\myfmt##1{\emph{##1}}
  \myfmt{Slide content}
\end{frame}
`. The `frame` environment is a pseudo-environment, i.e. actually `\frame{ .. }` in disguise. The argument is stored in a parameter-less macro and therefore the `#1` is taken as its argument.

Comment: Supplement: You need to use four hashes, apparently the content is expanded twice. Using `\def\myfmt####1{\emph{####1}}` works for me in the frame, **but** not with `\againframe`. So using `fragile` seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @Martin: That should be an answer.

Comment: @Martin: I had tried it with two `#`, but not with four, nice :-) However, `fragile` seems not to help wrt to `\againframe`; have you tested this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `frame` environment is a pseudo-environment, i.e. actually `\frame{ .. }` in disguise. The argument is stored in at least one parameter-less macro and therefore the `#1` is taken as its argument. You can try doubling the `#`s as usual in such cases. In my tests I needed to double all `#` twice: `\def\myfmt####1{\emph{####1}}`. This then works in the first frame, but not in the `\againframe`. Apparently the content is assigned there again and causes issues.

The easiest solution would be to use the `fragile` option for the frame which warns `beamer` about such issues and make it process the `frame` more carefully.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=noproblem,fragile]{A frame that uses a ,,local'' macro}
  \def\myfmt#1{\emph{#1}}
  \myfmt{Slide content}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Another frame that uses a ,,local'' macro}
  \def\myfmt#1{\color{red} #1}
  \myfmt{Slide content}
\end{frame}

\againframe{noproblem}

\end{document}
```

Also if you would hide the `#` from the `\frame` it would work, e.g. placing your definition inside another macro outside the frame and use that macro in the frame, but for doing this one would again need to define one macro outside the frame which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this works! As usual, I will wait a couple of days before accepting the answer. Comment: The only caveat with `fragile` is that it does not play together with `allowframebreaks`. However, a frame with local macros *and* frame-breaks that is used again with `\againframe` would be a pathological case anyway.

Comment: Very useful tip. I had the same problems with `\docsvlist` for sparklines inside a beamer document. Thanks.