# Conflict between beamer and forest

Tags: beamer, errors, forest, compilation-error

There appears to be a conflict when I'm using the `forest` package to build trees in a `beamer` presentation. Whenever I use the `delay` option (possibly only in combination with `content`, have not used it otherwise), the following error appears:

> ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \beamer@doifinframe.

Despite the error, a pdf is generated on Overleaf, providing the tree I wanted, but TeXworks is not that kind to me.

What is causing the error and how to solve it?

**MWE** (from the [`forest` documentation](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf#page=6))

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

        \begin{forest}  
            [roman, delay={for children={content=\romannumeral##1}}    
            [1][2][3][4]  
        ]\end{forest}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which renders:

[image: result]

Comment: Add `fragile` and drop a `#`: `\begin{frame}[fragile]

        \begin{forest}  
            [roman, delay={for children={content=\romannumeral#1}}    
            [1][2][3][4]  
        ]\end{forest}

\end{frame}`

Comment: Or, if you do not like `fragile`, use four (!) `#`: `\begin{frame}

        \begin{forest}  
            [roman, delay={for children={content=\romannumeral####1}}    
            [1][2][3][4]  
        ]\end{forest}

\end{frame}`. Why four? Because three is too little and five too much. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a way, this is a duplicate to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22327) and many others. As Martin Scharrer explains,

> The frame environment is a pseudo-environment, i.e. actually `\frame{ .. }` in disguise.

What that means is that one has to be careful with the `#`. `forest` is no exception to this, so the options are:

- use the `fragile` option, or
- double the `#` twice, i.e. quadruple them.

This leads to

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

        \begin{forest}  
            [roman, delay={for children={content=\romannumeral#1}}    
            [1][2][3][4]  
        ]\end{forest}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}

        \begin{forest}  
            [roman, delay={for children={content=\romannumeral####1}}    
            [1][2][3][4]  
        ]\end{forest}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This yields two identical frames:

[image]

In particular, there is no genuine conflict between `forest` and `beamer`, just the usual subtleties of defining and using macros with arguments in frames.